# Pulsing to grab attention

Tags: interaction-design, animation

I want to know what you guys think about a pulsing animation to grab attention to know about the advantages to login.
The idea is having a circle pulsing and when the user makes hover it shows a tooltip and he can click and know more. And after the user makes the login it disappears.
[image]

[image]

Comment: The pulsing is one thing but you should also consider whether having a clickable/hoverable tooltip on top of a clickable/hoverable button is really the best idea.

Comment: The circle looks like a very small target, why not use the entire button area instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would be wary of having something pulse on the screen with no way to make it stop. This kind of animation can be very distracting. I would caution you to not "annoy" the user into signing in.

In a project I'm currently working on, only the most severe errors that are still occurring use a pulsing animation.

Instead, **consider using an onboarding tooltip** that can inform the user of the benefits an account provides, but is easily dismissible. See the example from Slack below:

[image: Slack onboarding example.]
<sup>([Source](https://www.appcues.com/blog/the-5-best-user-onboarding-experiences))</sup>